# Writing a Python extension in C, and getting strange memory errors

Tags: python, numpy, cpython

I have a Python class I've written in C called `pyquat.Quat`, and it includes methods for multiplying by another Quat, returning a NumPy array (`Quat#to_matrix()`) and for printing the representation.

Sometimes when I call these methods, I get a `SIGSEGV`. However, the segmentation fault never occurs when I'm running the program in GDB.

Although I can't seem to trace the problem, I *am* seeing some weird cases of memory being overwritten (apparently). For example, here's my script and output:

```
>>> from pyquat import Quat
>>> z = Quat(4,3,2,1) * Quat(1,2,3,4)
>>> z
Quat{{-12, 6, 24, 12}}
>>> z.normalize()
Quat{{-0.40000000000000002, 0.20000000000000001, 0.80000000000000004, 0.40000000000000002}}
>>> m = z.to_matrix()
>>> m
array([[-0.6 ,  0.  ,  0.8 ],
       [ 0.64,  0.6 ,  0.48],
       [-0.48,  0.8 , -0.36]])
>>> z
'exc_traceback'
```

I've been doing a lot of searching, but I have no clue why it would be overwriting the caller with a string here.

The function in question is:

```
static PyObject* pyquat_Quat_to_matrix(PyObject* self) {
  npy_intp dims[2] = {3,3};

  pyquat_Quat* q = (pyquat_Quat*)(self);

  PyArrayObject* ary  = (PyArrayObject*)PyArray_SimpleNew(2, dims, NPY_DOUBLE);
  double* T = (double*)ary->data;

  T[0] = 1.0 - 2.0 * (q->v[2] * q->v[2] + q->v[1] * q->v[1]); 
  T[1] =       2.0 * (q->v[1] * q->v[0] +    q->s * q->v[2]);
  T[2] =       2.0 * (q->v[2] * q->v[0] -    q->s * q->v[1]);
  T[3] =       2.0 * (q->v[1] * q->v[0] -    q->s * q->v[2]);
  T[4] = 1.0 - 2.0 * (q->v[2] * q->v[2] + q->v[0] * q->v[0]);
  T[5] =       2.0 * (q->v[2] * q->v[1] +    q->s * q->v[0]);
  T[6] =       2.0 * (q->v[2] * q->v[0] +    q->s * q->v[1]);
  T[7] =       2.0 * (q->v[2] * q->v[1] -    q->s * q->v[0]);
  T[8] = 1.0 - 2.0 * (q->v[1] * q->v[1] + q->v[0] * q->v[0]);

  return PyArray_Return(ary);
}
```

and my type looks like

```
typedef struct {
  PyObject_HEAD

  /* Type-specific fields go here */
  double s;     // scalar component
  double v[3];  // vector components
} pyquat_Quat;
```

I'm fairly certain I'm correctly including numpy, and creating both my module and my class:

```
/* Initialize the pyquat module and add pyquat.Quat to it.  */
PyMODINIT_FUNC initpyquat(void) {
  PyObject* m;

  pyquat_QuatType.tp_new = PyType_GenericNew;
  if (PyType_Ready(&pyquat_QuatType) < 0)
    return;

  // Define the pyquat module.
  m = Py_InitModule3("pyquat", pyquat_methods,
         "Quaternion module with fast unit (right) quaternion math written in C.");

  // Import NumPy to prevent a segfault when we call a function that uses NumPy API.
  import_array();

  // Create the Quat class in the pyquat module.
  Py_INCREF(&pyquat_QuatType);
  PyModule_AddObject(m, "Quat", (PyObject *)&pyquat_QuatType);
}


static int pyquat_Quat_init(pyquat_Quat* self, PyObject* args) {

  double scalar, vx, vy, vz;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "dddd", &scalar, &vx, &vy, &vz))
    return -1;

  // Read the scalar and vector components of the quaternion.
  self->s = scalar;
  self->v[0] = vx;
  self->v[1] = vy;
  self->v[2] = vz;

  return 0;
}
```

My repr method seems pretty typical, too, but I notice that this method also occasionally causes `obj` to be overwritten.

```
static PyObject* pyquat_Quat_repr(PyObject* obj) {
  pyquat_Quat* self = (pyquat_Quat*)(obj);
  return PyString_FromFormat("Quat{{\%s, \%s, \%s, \%s}}", 
                             PyOS_double_to_string(self->s, 'g', 17, 0, NULL),
                             PyOS_double_to_string(self->v[0], 'g', 17, 0, NULL),
                             PyOS_double_to_string(self->v[1], 'g', 17, 0, NULL),
                             PyOS_double_to_string(self->v[2], 'g', 17, 0, NULL));
}


static PyObject * pyquat_Quat_mul(PyObject* self, PyObject* arg) {

  // Expects the one argument to be a pyquat_Quat
  if (!PyObject_IsInstance(arg, (PyObject*)&pyquat_QuatType)) {
    Py_DECREF(arg);
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IOError, "expected quaternion");
    return NULL;
  }

  pyquat_Quat* rhs    = (pyquat_Quat*)(arg);
  pyquat_Quat* lhs    = (pyquat_Quat*)(self);
  pyquat_Quat* result = (pyquat_Quat *)Py_TYPE(self)->tp_alloc(Py_TYPE(self), 0);

  result->s    = lhs->s * rhs->s - (lhs->v[0] * rhs->v[0] + lhs->v[1] * rhs->v[1] + lhs->v[2] * rhs->v[2]);
  result->v[0] = lhs->s * rhs->v[0] + rhs->s * lhs->v[0] - (lhs->v[1] * rhs->v[2] - lhs->v[2] * rhs->v[1]);
  result->v[1] = lhs->s * rhs->v[1] + rhs->s * lhs->v[1] - (lhs->v[2] * rhs->v[0] - lhs->v[0] * rhs->v[2]);
  result->v[2] = lhs->s * rhs->v[2] + rhs->s * lhs->v[2] - (lhs->v[0] * rhs->v[1] - lhs->v[1] * rhs->v[0]);

  return (PyObject*)(result);
}
```

This is one I have some concern about. It's returning `self` — but why does the multiplication function, which also returns an object, not also cause Python to echo the repr for the object?

**Edit:** After some investigation, it looks like the problem only happens when I call the in-place normalization routine. Do I need to increment or decrement some reference counter here?

```
static PyObject* pyquat_Quat_inplace_normalize(PyObject* self) {

  pyquat_Quat* q = (pyquat_Quat*)(self);

  double q_mag = sqrt(q->s * q->s + q->v[0] * q->v[0] + q->v[1] * q->v[1] + q->v[2] * q->v[2]);
  if (q_mag > PYQUAT_QUAT_SMALL) q_mag = 1.0 / q_mag;
  else                           q_mag = 0.0;

  q->s    *= q_mag;
  q->v[0] *= q_mag;
  q->v[1] *= q_mag;
  q->v[2] *= q_mag;

  return self;
}
```

Here is the multiplication function:

```
static PyObject * pyquat_Quat_mul(PyObject* self, PyObject* arg) {

  // Expects the one argument to be a pyquat_Quat
  if (!PyObject_IsInstance(arg, (PyObject*)&pyquat_QuatType)) {
    Py_DECREF(arg);
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IOError, "expected quaternion");
    return NULL;
  }

  pyquat_Quat* rhs    = (pyquat_Quat*)(arg);
  pyquat_Quat* lhs    = (pyquat_Quat*)(self);
  pyquat_Quat* result = (pyquat_Quat *)Py_TYPE(self)->tp_alloc(Py_TYPE(self), 0);

  result->s    = lhs->s * rhs->s - (lhs->v[0] * rhs->v[0] + lhs->v[1] * rhs->v[1] + lhs->v[2] * rhs->v[2]);
  result->v[0] = lhs->s * rhs->v[0] + rhs->s * lhs->v[0] - (lhs->v[1] * rhs->v[2] - lhs->v[2] * rhs->v[1]);
  result->v[1] = lhs->s * rhs->v[1] + rhs->s * lhs->v[1] - (lhs->v[2] * rhs->v[0] - lhs->v[0] * rhs->v[2]);
  result->v[2] = lhs->s * rhs->v[2] + rhs->s * lhs->v[2] - (lhs->v[0] * rhs->v[1] - lhs->v[1] * rhs->v[0]);

  return (PyObject*)(result);
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might debug this more effectively, or see what the problem could be?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem if you compile without ASLR (or if you enable ASLR under gdb)? I'm assuming that you are using ASLR, of course

Comment: No. It does make it more sensitive. For example, this time I get `<refcnt -1222254038 at 0xb725e200>`, but it doesn't actually segfault.

Comment: If you see `<refcnt -1222254038 at 0xb725e200>` you are still experiencing an erratic behavior. That memory region is readable, so you don't get a segfault, but still that is not a valid Python object. This can be a good starting point for debugging. By the way, I guess that to obtain such result you have disable ASLR, which is why you have more chances of getting a readable memory address. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I did have to disable ASLR, as you suggested — and also compiled with `-g -O0` flags.

Answer (score 1):

You said that by `Py_INCREF` some values before returning them from your methods, the problem seems to disappear.

Inspired by your discovery, I found the problem:

```
static PyObject * pyquat_Quat_mul(PyObject* self, PyObject* arg) {
  // Expects the one argument to be a pyquat_Quat
  if (!PyObject_IsInstance(arg, (PyObject*)&pyquat_QuatType)) {
    Py_DECREF(arg);
```

You are `Py_DECREF`ing arguments. You should not do that! Refcounts should be increased and decreased only when objects are stored somewhere.

Comment: Ohhh. Okay. That's the clearest most concise answer I've seen so far. Do you want to incorporate my answer into yours and I'll mark yours as accepted? (Thanks!!)

Comment: @Dr.JohnnyMohawk: did I incorporate your answer into mine?

Comment: @Dr.JohnnyMohawk: actually what I wrote is not accurate. Your `Py_INCREF` from your answer is indeed required, because you are in fact returning a new reference to it. However, still, you should not `Py_DECREF` arguments. Tomorrow I'm writing a clearer and more detailed answer, time to sleep now! :)

Comment: in the meantime, be sure to read https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html?highlight=py_incref#reference-counting-in-python

Comment: ...no, I'm saying if you would combine your answer with mine, I would upvote it and mark it as correct. It seems that both answers are correct. I wanted to give you credit for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I found a solution.

The problem is in my in-place functions, which also return `self`.

For example,

```
static PyObject* pyquat_Quat_inplace_normalize(PyObject* self) {

  pyquat_Quat* q = (pyquat_Quat*)(self);

  double q_mag = sqrt(q->s * q->s + q->v[0] * q->v[0] + q->v[1] * q->v[1] + q->v[2] * q->v[2]);
  if (q_mag > PYQUAT_QUAT_SMALL) q_mag = 1.0 / q_mag;
  else                           q_mag = 0.0;

  q->s    *= q_mag;
  q->v[0] *= q_mag;
  q->v[1] *= q_mag;
  q->v[2] *= q_mag;

  Py_INCREF(self); # THIS

  return self;
}
```

I had to add a `Py_INCREF(self)` since `self` is both an argument and the return value.

This appears to fix the problem.